# Renaming a misspelled tag? / Rep requirement for synonym suggestions?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently there is a tag [hp-pavillion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hp-pavillion) aimed at HP Pavilion laptops; this tag is actually misspelled. I've tagged my question [Regular audio corruption when listening to music](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311034/audio-corruption-when-changing-volume) with [hp-pavilion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hp-pavilion), but can't link this tag to the main one, nor correct the typo in the original as I am unable to suggest synonyms.

As an aside: why is the rep requirement for merely *suggesting* a tag synonym so high, especially compared to that for suggesting edits to posts? Intuitively I'd have thought people would have to wait longer to edit others' posts than to edit tags, since tags seem to be a relatively minor thing but a careless edit could completely change the meaning of a question (I've seen a couple of edits around that have changed the title of a question so that it then asks the exact opposite of the body, for instance)

I understand the point brought up elsewhere that people should understand the system before being able to make changes, but to my mind that should come down to those reviewing suggestions rather than the people making them, surely?

Comment: I've re-tagged all questions tagged as `hp-pavillion` to `hp-pavilion`. Let's wait till `hp-pavillion` tag gets deleted.

Comment: @virpara, Cool... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would involve retagging all the questions with the wrong one, using the correct one. And then a moderator might be able to remove the wrong tag.

***Update:***

- From other stackexchange sites, it seems that a tag that is not used from any question is deleted within 24 hours.
  So we'll just have to replace the tags in the questions with the wrong tag, with the correct one, and then the wrong one will get removed automatically.
  **Courtesy:**
  https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2538/21849
- I have edited and added a tag wiki `excerpt` for [hp-pavilion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hp-pavilion)
- There are 115 questions tagged with [hp-pavillion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hp-pavillion)(Infomation from https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hp-pavillion), which have to be retagged.
- The 115 questions have been retagged by @virpara, now its only a matter of time until the wrong tag gets removed automatically.

**Official Information:**
Finally found the official detail regarding tag removal:
Any tags not currently in use, or that happen to get orphaned through unusual means (rollback, merge, etc), are removed every 24 hours [by a background process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40724/what-currently-happens-to-zombie-tags).

**Courtesy:**
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48418/184655