# What can be done about a tag that was obviously misspelled that I can't correct at my level?

Tags: discussion, support

The question that prompted mine is [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes). the tag in question is system-managment which I would never find is I was looking for questions regarding system-management. I have reviewed [Can misspelled tags be deleted?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2236/can-misspelled-tags-be-deleted) and [Renaming a misspelled tag? / Rep requirement for synonym suggestions?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6886/renaming-a-misspelled-tag-rep-requirement-for-synonym-suggestions)

Answer (score 1):

Or drop by in chat. BTW, that question is Community Wikify'ed, so anyone with 100 reputation can edit it without revision and you only need 300 rep to create a tag.

Comment: Sorry, but what is CW'ed?

Comment: @ElderGeek community wiki.

Comment: Thank you, that is useful information. I replaced the tag with System. (I tried to create a synonym which of course I couldn't do)

Answer (score 0):

Flag the question for moderator attention is my best guess.